# DirectX 9 projection matrix infinite element?

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, directx-9

I've been banging my head on doing transformations in DirectX 9 and during debugging I finally noticed a problem, when calling

```
D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&projection, D3DX_PI/4, yRes/xRes, 1, 100);
```

the first element (_11) of projection is #INF, which I'm pretty sure it should not be. This is directly after declaring this matrix and directly before assigning it to the projection transform of DirectX.

Background: I used custom vectors with RHW set to 1 so I got the orthographic view I was supposed to, I also got index buffers working. What has changed since is the addition of the matrices, as seen in [Drunken Hyena](http://www.drunkenhyena.com/cgi-bin/view_cpp_article.pl?chapter=2;article=27) and [DirectXTutorial.com](http://www.directxtutorial.com/Lesson.aspx?lessonid=9-4-5) but not I can't see any model. I have tried placing the camera on the other side (since one face of each triangle is rendered) and moving it out, as well as scaling up the mode (as was my problem in XNA), but I still only see the background image or the color I clear the screen to.

Code added:

```
void setTransforms()
{
    D3DXMATRIX final;
    D3DXMATRIX translate;
    D3DXMATRIX rotate;
    D3DXMATRIX scale;

    D3DXMatrixIdentity(&final);
    D3DXMatrixTranslation(&translate, 0, 0, 1);

    static float f = 0;
    D3DXMatrixRotationY(&rotate,f++/1000);

    D3DXMatrixScaling(&scale, 100.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f);

    D3DXMatrixMultiply(&final, &final, &scale);
    D3DXMatrixMultiply(&final, &final, &rotate);
    D3DXMatrixMultiply(&final, &final, &translate);

    pd3dDevice->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &final);

    //---- Projection

    D3DXMATRIX projection;
    D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&projection, D3DX_PI/4, yRes/xRes, 1, 100);

    pd3dDevice->SetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &projection);

    //~~~~ Projection
    //---- Camera / viewport

    D3DXMATRIX camera;
    D3DXVECTOR3 camPos(-10,0,0);
    D3DXVECTOR3 camTarget(0,0,0);
    D3DXVECTOR3 camUp(0,1,0);
    D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&camera, &camPos, &camTarget, &camUp);

    pd3dDevice->SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &camera);

    //~~~~ Camera

    pd3dDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING, FALSE);
}
```

and this function is called before I do the rendering stuff (I've tried both before and after begin() at various stages). The only change from the previous, working code, other than this, is the removal of RHW, all else is correct, including buffer sizes.

Any help or idea is welcome, thanks in advance!

Comment: Are `yRes` and `xRes` declared as `int`?

Comment: Just to add to the previous comment, if both variables are `int`, `y/x` may be `0`. BTW, the aspect ratio is [width by height](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205350%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and not the other way around.

Comment: Yes, yRes and xRes are indeed integers, casting them fixed the infinite element! I doubt I would have thought of it, thanks a lot! still nothing being rendered though, but debugging goes on.. Since you answered the question of the title, you may want to post is as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: I will post it as an answer. Thanks. BTW, you may need to check your division to make it sure you are dividing width by height and not the other way around.

Comment: Corrected that one too, but it won't make much difference 'till I get something drawn unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are `yRes` and `xRes` declared as `int`?
If that's the case, the division `y/x` may be `0`. Try casting one of the variables to `float`.

In addition, I noticed that you are calculating the aspect ratio using `yRes/xRes`.

If you are using `yRes` for height and `xRes` for width, you will have to change the division to `xRes/(double)yRes`.

The aspect ratio expected by `D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH` is [width by height](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205350%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and not the other way around.

Comment: That's what caused the infinity in the matrix, thanks